# DC Bias and Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, voltage-divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zaXF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to add a DC volatage of 1.25V to a sine wave signal. I am using a DC bias circuit with a voltage divider (R1=R2=100Kohm) connected to a 2.5V source and to the ground. That is giving me the correct 1.25V DC offset that I need in my application.

However I would like to lower the impedance so I am using a voltage follower op amp. I am using the LT6202 op amp which is supposed to be rail-to-rail and unity gain stable. When I connect the voltage follower to the DC bias circuit I mentioned above, the DC offset rises from 1.25V to 1.32V.I have done the simulation also and I am getting the same results.

When I am using R1=R2=10KOhm instead of 100KOhm the DC offset becomes 1.258V, which is closer to the wanted 1.25V value.

I am not sure what is causing that. Any help?

Comment: You need to show us your schematic if we're to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: Where are you measuring the offset? At the input or the output?

Comment: The offset is measured both in the input off the op amp and at the output and is for both around 1.236V with a real small flactuation between those two points.

Comment: Where's your input signal in the schematic? You say it's 1.23V, which is very close to the desired 1.25V, but don't mention that in your question - which figure is correct?

Comment: I do not have an input signal on that schematic, I am trying to understand at the moment why I am not getting the expected 1.25V from the above circuit but I am getting a 1.32V DC offset instead. The input signal will be connected at the C1 at the side that is currently connected to the ground.

Comment: just a correction 1.326 is what I am getting not 1.236, which is also close to 1.25, I just try to understand what is behind that number and I am not having the 1.25V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonideal opamps have input bias current - that is, they source or sink a small amount of current from their inputs. If you look at the [LT6202 datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/620234fd.pdf), you can see that for this opamp, with Vcm at half-rail voltage (which is roughly the case here), bias current will be between -7 and -1.3 microamps. This is sourcing current into your resistor divider and affecting the setpoint, equivalent to having a smaller resistor in the top half of your divider.

You can use lower value resistors to reduce the error - at the cost of more wasted current - or find an opamp with smaller input bias current.

Answer (score 1):

Your [LT6202](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/620234fd.pdf) has an input bias current of -8 uA to + 2.5 uA.  That coupled with the 100 k ohm will give you a big offset voltage.  Pick another oapmp or reduce the resistor values.